# How to prevent no commit message in Source Tree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, commit-message

Seems that we can commit with no message in Source Tree, but I want others not to do it in my project.

Comment: As [suggested](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Require-non-empty-commit-messages-for-git/qaq-p/371821) in Atlassian's forum, you can use an external plugin called [Midori](http://www.midori-global.com/products/better-commit-policy-for-jira/documentation/#message-pattern-condition) to apply a regular expression to commit messages.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by an plugins called **Midori**

You can do this with the Commit Policy Plugin using the [the commit message must match a regular expression condition](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-commit-policy-plugin/documentation/#message-pattern-condition).

This can verify the commit both [locally](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-commit-policy-plugin/documentation/git#installing-local-commit-hooks) and on the [server](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-commit-policy-plugin/documentation/git) for ultimate security.

Comment: Thank you for the information!
Midori seems not free for using, is there any plugin like this? or is there any way to custom Source Tree?